# Extract value from URL and set it as variable

Tags: excel, vba

I want to double-click a cell in Excel to open a URL.

I've been using VBA for this aspect, but I am facing an issue.
I want to extract a value from URL and use it as variable in VBA.

Here is part of the script:

```vb
Dim ID As String
          
ID = ActiveSheet.Range("S" & Target.Cells.Row & "").Value
    
rptUrl = "http://...=" + ID
         
If (ID <> "") Then
          
    ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink (rptUrl)
```

In such case, if the ID is at the end of the URL, it works.

What happens if the ID that I want to extract is somewhere in the middle of the URL, and not at the end?

For example:

```
rptUrl = "http://..**ID**..="
```

I tried the following:

```
rptUrl = "http://.. + **ID** + ..="
```

Comment: How do you know where the ID starts and ends? Can you show some sample URLs that show a bit more details than the ones you posted? You can use fake information, but it will help to understand.

Comment: Thanks basodre for your immediate response.

Sample URL:

http://mysrv.com/form.jsp?id=12345&cn=0

The value I want is right after id= and just before &cn, and the length could vary, it could be 4, 5, 6 character-long.

Comment: Basically, you need some string handling functions like `Pos`,  `Mid`, `Split`, or try regular expressions. But you should provide some examples. And please edit your question and format the code as *code*

Comment: Thanks FunThomas, I have formatted the code.
Unfortunately I am not familiar with those functions, I'll have a look at them.

Comment: The ID is part of the parameter list of the URL. Since it does not matter where a parameter is located in the parameter list, there are exactly two possibilities. Either it is the first parameter, which is always behind the question mark (?) or it is a parameter somewhere behind it, then it is always behind an ampersand (&). So the first thing I would do is to cut off the parameter list at the question mark. Then divide the list at the ampersand and finally find the desired parameter from the elements. By myself, I only can do this with VBA, but it probably works with formulas as well.

Comment: Provide realistic examples with expected output. Some basic string manipulation will probably get you without VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a regular expression, here's an option that packages the regular expression into a function that you can call. If the URL contains "ID", it will return the corresponding value; otherwise, it will just return a blank string

```
Function GetId(sInput) As String
    Dim oReg As Object
    Dim m As Variant
    Dim sOutput As String
    
    sOutput = ""
    
    Set oReg = CreateObject("VBScript.Regexp")
    
    With oReg
        .Global = False
        .ignorecase = True
        .MultiLine = False
        .Pattern = "id=(\w+)[&|$]"
    End With
    
    
    If oReg.Test(sInput) Then
        sOutput = oReg.Execute(sInput)(0).submatches(0)
    End If
    
    GetId = sOutput
End Function

Sub Test()
    Debug.Print GetId("mysrv.com/form.jsp?id=12345&cn=0")
End Sub
```